# What is the horn of Amalek?

Tags: rashi, tehilim-psalms, amalek

[Tehillim 75:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.75.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states:

> וכל־קרני רשעים אגדע תרוממנה קרנות צדיק
>
> All the horns of the wicked I will cut; but the horns of the righteous shall be lifted up.

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.75.11?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Psalms.75.11.1&lang2=bi) explains that the horns of the wicked refers to Amalek

> וכל קרני רשעים: של עמלק
>
> אגדע: כענין שנא' (יחזקאל כ״ה:י״ד) ונתתי את נקמתי באדום ביד עמי ישראל ישראל יגדעו קרן עמלק וגו

However the verse in יחזקאל does not mention cutting the horn of Amalek.
I would like to understand what this horn (symbolically) is and why Rashi says that the horns referenced in Tehillim are a reference to Amalek. I did not see any other commentary (from those available on Sefaria) who made a similar connection to Amalek.

Comment: Is he equating Amalek with his grandfather Edom?

Comment: Your title doesn’t match your body. Suggested edit: Why does Rashi introduce the horn of Amalek?

Comment: It looks like Sefaria has a typo on the Rashi to Tehillim 75:11. Mikra'ot Gadolot says "של אויב", not "של עמלק".  http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=275

Comment: The Ibn Ezra uses the expression, "על בלק" which is close to their typo.

Comment: @YaacovDeane יגדעו קרן anything doesn’t appear in the prooftext, even with the Mikraos Gedolos that reads it as אויב there as well.

Comment: @DonielF Rashi's quote from Yechezkel ends at "עמי ישראל". Then linguistically, he starts a new phrase (like placing a comma after his quotation if it were in English) by saying, "Israel will (in the future) cut off the keren of Amalek." He isn't reading the Rashi correctly. FYI, in this context, the "keren" is a reference to the 'Anti-Moshiach' who is a parallel to Moshiach. It follows Sefer Karnayim.

Comment: @DonielF hopefully my edit clarified.

Comment: @rikitikitembo Rashi isn't saying what you are claiming. He's just giving an additional example of the usage of Israel cutting keren in connection with the enemies of Israel and G-d. (the keren of Esav, the keren of the enemy, the keren of Amalek, etc.) Your confusion is over the lack of punctuation.

Comment: @rikitikitembo See the same type of language usage in Megillah 17b which quotes the same sources.

Comment: @YaacovDeane in my print mikraot gedolot it has both readings with the Amalek as the preferred girsa in at least one.

Comment: @rikitikitembo I understand. The usage as Amalek appears to be a typo or censors change from what I see. Malbim also brings אויב in the Rashi text and adds the punctuation (commas) to clarify how to read as I have stated in my comments here. I just ordered Mayer Gruber’s book on Rashi to Tehillim to see if he remarks about the variations. But it’s hard to believe that Rashi would bring something that doesn’t follow Shas, Targum, and Midrash. No source that I have found specifies Amalek.

Comment: FWIW, I just finished reviewing the Tehillim with commentary Shemen Sasson by Rabbi Yaacov Tzvi Yolles which includes Rashi’s commentary. He brings Rashi’s text the same way it is found by Malbim. Rabbi Yolles was very careful to use correct texts. It would be interesting to know when the variant occurred.

Comment: @rikitikitembo Does it say why the version with Amalek is preferred? Does it give a source for this nusach, meaning a specific, authoritative manuscript by or at least close to the time and location of Rashi?

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects to your question.

The first is to try to determine if the text for Rashi’s comments to Tehillim 75:11 as found in the Sefaria version is correct and accurate or not.

Then, the second aspect is to address your primary question as stated in the heading and recapped in your closing paragraph.

On the first aspect, the accuracy of text of Rashi on Tehillim, the authoritative and critical edition of Rashi’s commentary on Psalms by [Rabbi, Professor Mayer I. Gruber](https://prabook.com/web/mayer_irwin.gruber/553355) republished in paperback by JPS in 2004 is important.

As Gruber discusses in detail in pages 158-164, after reviewing over 60 extant handwritten manuscripts, most dating from the 13th, 14th and 15th centuries, he determined that virtually all printed editions, including Parshandatha by [Rabbi Yitzchok Maarsen](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/maarsen-isaac) are corrupted and inaccurate. Gruber goes on to explain that he relied primarily on two handwritten manuscripts known as Oppenheim 34 and Vienna 220. The details of why are quite interesting and worth the read if you can find a copy of Gruber’s book, which is currently in print.

The correct text of Rashi to Tehillim 75:11 for the words, “וכל קרני רשעי׳״ is actually:

> של עשו הרשע

There is no mention of Amalek whatsoever.

It then adds a *final Mem* to עגדע**ם** to indicate that *they*, the *Rasha’im* from Esav will be cut down, and continues with the citation from Ezekial 25:14.

> כעניין שנ׳ ונתתי נקמתי באדום ביד עמי ישר׳ ישר׳ יגדעו קרן עשו

So that resolves your question about the discrepancy concerning the mention of Amalek, which is not found in the Navi Rashi cites. The correct text of Rashi is consistent and accurate with the appropriate Navi.

The second aspect of your question, about what the meaning of this *horn* is in regard to Esav, can be found in the introduction of [Rabbi Eliezer Fishel ben Rabbi Yitzchok of Krakow](https://www.jewishgen.org/Yizkor/Strzyzow/str010.html) to his super commentary *Parshat Eliezer* to Sefer Karnayim with the commentary of [Rabbi Shimshon of Ostropole](http://www.yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Shimshon_ben_Pesah_of_Ostropolye).

I[n paragraphs 3 and 4,](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7434&st=&pgnum=4) he explains how the concept of *horn* (קרן) as it pertains to Israel in the context of the final redemption means *Moshiach* like is found in [Habakkuk 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Habakkuk.3.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) which says, “קרנים מידו לו”. He goes on to explain how this is referring to both Moshiach ben Yosef and Moshiach ben David.

As he explains further on in the book in [the 14th discourse](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7434&st=&pgnum=88), just as there is a *Moshiach* for Israel (actually two, ben Yosef and ben David) the side of Holiness, there is also an *anti-Moshiach* for the *other side*. In the context of Tehillim 75:11, (וכל קרני רשעים של עשו) the Moshiachs of the *Rasha’im of Esav*.

And this principle, including Rashi referencing Israel and Esav is in keeping with Bereshit 25:23-24 which addresses the conception and birth of the fraternal twins, Yaacov (*Yisroel*) and Esav. Please take note of Rashi’s comments to the citation from Bereshit.

Comment: I really want to mark this answer correct however the second part is based on the sefer Karnayim which has been shown to be a forgery see Yehuda Liebes, “Mysticism and Reality: Towards a Portrait of the Martyr and Kabbalist, R. Samson Ostropoler,” in Jewish Thought in the Seventeenth Century, ed. Isadore Twersky and Bernard Septimus, pp. 221–255 (Cambridge, Mass., 1987)

Comment: @rikitikitembo You might want to actually read the introduction of Rabbi Shimshon to Sefer Karnayim. Many, many gadolim over many centuries have accepted Sefer Karnayim as authoritative and legitimate. According to the opinion of Rabbi Shimshon, it was likely written by the author of Igeret HaTa'amim which follows the same type of approach. However, Rabbi Shimshon notes that according to many, it was authored by the son of the Ra'avad.

Comment: I have read the sefer, actually before I read professor Liebes's article and reached the same conclusion independently.

Comment: @rikitikitembo I'll need to finish reading the article from Tarbitz by Yehuda Liebes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehuda_Liebes), but from what I have read so far, his issue is not with Sefer Karnayim. It is with Rabbi Shimshon of Ostropole. FWIW, Yehuda Liebes, according to his Wikipedia bio, also denies the legitimacy of the Zohar, and all Breslovers and says that the students of the Gaon of Vilna are heavily influenced by Shabbtai Tzvi. Liebes is definitely not mainstream and, at best, should be considered 'daat yachid'.

Comment: @rikitikitembo You read/learned the entire Sefer Karnayim? Wow, I've been learning it for months and am not close to finishing  it (even though it is only 14 small discourses) or comprehending what it is actually saying. For you to just blow right through it and conclude it is a forgery, you must be one of the leading Gedolei Torah of this entire generation! Imagine how all those giants of Torah from all those previous generations simply got it wrong.

Comment: just something worth considering, try reading it without dan yadin and see if it makes any sense at all. then consider if there are any works you can think of in Judaism that make literally zero sense without one specific commentary. I'm sure R' Shimshon HY"D was a great man but if you look at the facts dispassionately I don't think you would conclude differently.

Comment: @rikitikitembo Like many things from Rabbi Shimshon (if you have learned them at all) their language is very compact. And the actual author of Sefer Karnayim (whether Rabbi Aharon of Cardina AKA Constantinople or the anonymous son of the Ra'avad as Rabbi Shimshon notes in his Hakdama) is even more compact than Rabbi Shimon. They take a lot of work. Does Sefer Karnayim make sense? Everything that I have worked through is flawless and correct. It has only validated why so many true, Torah giants over the last 200 years speak so highly of Rabbi Shimshon, HY"D.

Comment: Perhaps you are right and I am simply misunderstanding his works or perhaps not. I don't know who all the giants you refer to are. I am familiar with the glowing references to Dan Yadin by R' Tzvi Elimelech of Dinov but I also believe the author of the Megaleh Amukot distanced himself from R' Shimon. I would also point out that Professor Liebes is not a dat yachid in this matter, AFAIK the entire scholarly community supports his assessment. http://www.yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Shimshon_ben_Pesah_of_Ostropolye